# Radius of convergence of a complex power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let's say I have a series which converges in a radius $R$ about point $a$. Let's say I expand the same about point $b$. How does the radius of convergence change?

My progress so far :- I obtain it to be $R-|a-b|$. However I clearly have points outside this radius where the series converges, such as $b$. What's wrong in this argument?

Comment: One can get inequalities only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Andre* said in a comment, all you get is an inequality, because you have in general no idea how the function behaves at or outside the radius of convergence. For example, both $( z \mapsto \frac{1}{z-3} )$ and $( z \mapsto \frac{1}{z^2-9} )$ have a power series around $0$ with radius of convergence $3$, but the first has a power series around $-3$ with radius of convergence $6$ while the second does not even have a power series around $-3$. Also, both have a power series around $-1$ but different radius of convergence.

All you know is that if $b$ is within the original convergence disk around $a$, then we can guarantee that the power series around $b$ certainly will converge within a disk that fits in $a$, such as the disk of radius $R - |a-b|$.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing' wrong. Example : $f(z)=1(1-z)$ is analytic except at $z=1$ so if you expand $f$ as a power series about some point $b \ne 1$, the radius of convergence is  $|b-1|$.

Comment: |z-a|<R→|z-b-a+b|<R→|z-b|-|a-b|<R→|z-b|<R+|a-b|

Answer (score -1):

Use |z-a|≧|z-b|-|a-b| to get the result as R+|a-b|

Comment: Kalpesh..why u vote down when u dnt understand the answer